# Lua ¿como convertir un string en una variable?

Tags: lua

Quiero tomar el nombre de un archivo y crear una variable con ese nombre
¿es siquiera posible hacer eso?
como un `tostring()` pero a la inversa.

Comment: Lo del `tostring()` pero a la inversa me confunde un poco, ya que entiendo que lo que buscas es que si tienes una cadena como `"test"` se cree una variable llamada `test`. Pero `tostring()`no sería la inversa de eso, ya que si tienes una variable llamada `test` y haces `tostring(test)` no te va a salir  `"test"`, sino el valor que hubiera en `test` convertido en cadena (por ejemplo `"1"` si `test` valía `1`).

Comment: ah, lo usé como ejemplo porque sé que puedes acceder a los valores de una tabla usando strings, digo, como `laTabla[numero1 =1]` `print( laTabla["numero"..variableNumero] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Lua existe una variable global llamada `G_` que es un diccionario que contiene todos los nombres de variables globales como claves (y sus correspondientes valores).

Es decir, si tu programa tiene una variable llamada `x` que vale 1, entonces existe la clave `_G["x"]` y tiene valor 1.

En ese diccionario es posible crear claves nuevas, que creo que es justamente lo que estás preguntando. Así por ejemplo:

```
nombre = "prueba"
_G[nombre] = "Ha funcionado?"
```

creará una variable global llamada `prueba` con el valor `"Ha funcionado?"` como puedes comprobar seguidamente:

```
print(prueba)
```

Comment: Si, funciona!  ̶A̶h̶í̶ ̶v̶a̶ ̶o̶t̶r̶o̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶a̶ ̶e̶n̶ ̶l̶u̶a̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶c̶i̶o̶n̶a̶ ̶u̶s̶a̶n̶d̶o̶ ̶u̶n̶a̶ ̶t̶a̶b̶l̶a̶